# objective c. ScrollView: how to force it redraw visible part each time user scrolls?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've got my own dynamically changing view inside scrollview.

As my view is very big I usually redraw only it's visible part.

But when I scroll up or down drawRect method isn't being called.

I guess scroll view has a buffer to quickly react on user actions but I don't know exactly a mechanism how it works.

---

UPD

Thanks to Wienke, I've got a solution: to implement UIScrollViewDelegate.

I've implemented scrollViewDidScroll method:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin = [scrollView contentOffset];
    visibleRect.size = [scrollView bounds].size;
    [textField setNeedsDisplayInRect:visibleRect];
}
```

So every time user scrolls even a little this method redraws the whole visible part. That's bad=(

How can I redraw only... Let me call that "new region that appeared after scrolling". I guess it's much faster...

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: That's what the "InRect" part of "setNeedsDisplayInRect" is for. Your "visibleRect" variable should be the bounds of the scrollview's content view.

Comment: Wow... I was sure that "InRect" is exactly the rect that would be passed to drawRect: method.... Rule#1: Never be sure - always check=) Thanks again

Comment: While you're at it, check out "View Geometry" from Apple's View Programming Guide. You can apply what you're finding out now to lots of other situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried assigning a scrollview delegate? The UIScrollViewDelegate protocol includes methods like scrollViewDidEndDragging, upon which you could redraw.

Comment: I guess that can help but I was looking for a way to clean scrollview's buffer.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you.. You showed me the right direction to dig to=) I've used scrollViewDidScroll - it was better for my problem.